# batch script to delete certain files based upon one file (format vary sometimes) exist in all sub folders

Tags: batch-file

I had some subfolders under main folder like below

- \main\sub1
- \main\sub2
  ...........

Within these sub folders, there are basically 3 type of files as standard as below in sub1:

- 9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D
- 9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D.txt
- 9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D.M71
- 9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D.pkg

in sub2:  the txt file and pkg file lack of P3? in its name

- 9980000001110000_00000000NARC.txt
- 9980000001110000_00000000NARC.P3D
- 9980000001110000_00000000NARC.P3D.M71
- 9980000001110000_00000000NARC.pkg

.....

Now I can use below code
    CD main
    FOR /R %%G IN (*.TXT) DO IF EXIST "%%~dpnG" DEL "%%~dpnG"

to delete **9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D** in sub1. I can not delete the **9980000001110000_00000000NARC.P3D** in sub2

Is any way to have deleted *.P3? file in both Sub1 and sub2 based upon the condition if exist *.txt in that sub folder ...

I hope I put it clear...

Thanks

Comment: Is the trailing asterisk in your files meant to be literal, or any appendix?

Comment: Your input examples are not matching your output code examples.

Comment: trailing asterisk mean literal.

Comment: Sorry confusing. I just added take sub5 folder as example since it had nonstandard format of files, so the output is not expected

Comment: The character **`*`** is not allowed in a file name.

Comment: There is no way you got that output with the code and input example you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another best guess based upon your poor explanation:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R . *.p3? 2^>Nul') Do @If Exist "%%~dpnA*.pkg" (If Exist "%%~dpnA*.txt" Del /A /F "%%A" >Nul 2>&1)
```

Comment: @goodywp, I have made a very small change, _I will be making no more!_

Answer (score 0):

After your comments, I think this is what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R %%i in (*.txt) do (
  if exist "%%~dpni.pkg" set "fn=%%~dpni" & for %%a in (!fn!) do del %%~dpna*
)
```

We do a search for `*.txt` and get their name, regardless of what they are called. Then we test if the same filename (excluding the `.txt` extension) and adding a `.pkg` extension. Then we run another loop to again remove any extension, which in the case after the name was stripped from the extension could/could not contain `P3*` then if this condition is true, it means we found both `filename.txt` and `filename.pkg` ( no matter if it contains P3* or not) then we simply run `del filename* (ecluding P3* and exluding any extension.

Again, *note* I added echo before the `del` commands so you can test and only print the result, only remove `echo` from the last line `do echo del %%~dpna*` once you are happy with what the results print to screen.

Comment: Thanks! just some simplify the question in above POST.

Comment: then set a variable, get rid of P3 in the name and do a wild card on that delete. simple as that.

Comment: @goodywp I tell you what, edit your question, add REAL examles of files so I can see exactly what they look like, do not add funny * characters or anything, just show actual file pairs.

Comment: there is some folders also having P3* but not want to be deleted only if that P3* file have abcedfg.P3D.txt and abcdefg.P3D.pkg exist.

Comment: @goodywp ok, See edited answer, if I understood your requirement, this is what you want.

Comment: @goodywp because you did not read my post completely, it will show you what it will do, to actually delete it, remove the `echo` from the string. I will remove it from my answer now and you try again.

Comment: @goodywp I removed the echo for you, copy the code and try again.

Comment: @goodywp, I am not going to support this thread any longer, your requirements keeps on changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /r %%G in (*.P3?) do if exist "%%~G.txt" del "%%~G"
```

This will delete in `sub1`

- `9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D`

if exist

- `9980000000113100_2C8C6ADEPatT.P3D.txt`

which does exist, so it does delete.

---

This will delete in `sub2`

- `9980000001110000_00000000NARC.P3D`

if exist

- `9980000001110000_00000000NARC.P3D.txt`

which does not exist, so nothing to delete.